# Rails associating multiple :has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and trying to understand associating entities.

I have three entities right now: Users, Companies, and Productlines.

company.rb:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :productlines
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company
end
```

productline.rb:

```
class Productline < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end
```

I've done the migration scrips to associate them, however when I click into a Company on Rails Admin, I'm getting this:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: productlines.company_id: SELECT "productlines".* FROM "productlines" WHERE "productlines"."company_id" = ?
Extracted source (around line #91):
#
def prepare sql
  stmt = SQLite3::Statement.new( self, sql )
  return stmt unless block_given?

begin

**Edit: Here is my migration:**

```
class AddProductlineIdToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :companies, :productline_id, :integer
    add_index :companies, :productline_id
  end
end
```

Comment: post your migrations.... the `company_id` is missing in the `productlines` table

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: Did you remember to run `rake db:migrate` after adding that migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `company_id` to `productlines` and not `product_line_id` to `companies`...

```
class AddCompanyIdToProductlines < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :productlines, :company_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Do I need to rollback the previous migration?

Comment: yep: `rake db:rollback`